How do I change the y-scale and spacing between plots in ggplot2?

I need the y-axis of all 3 plots to be the same (max being 0.6 should be good) and I need to group ΨTort|Ig.Pr and ΨTort|Ig.Ab together in plot a, ΨIg.NT and ΨIg.T together as well as ΨTort.T and ΨTort.NT together in plot b, and ΨIg.SP and ΨIg.PP as well as ΨTort.SP and ΨTort.PP in plot c. (See image attached... arrows on bottom show items which should be moved/grouped closer together for easier comparison... arrows on top show scale which should all be the same)
EDIT: I got chatGPT to fix the scale problem, but it could not group the desired parameters closer together. So the following code produces figures with the desired scale but the parameters are still all spaced evenly even though there is mention of grouping them within the code which was added by chatGPT.
Here is my code:
`library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

# Combine Parameters for Plot A
d.conditional <- data.frame(parameter = c("ΨIg", "ΨTort|Ig.Pr", "ΨTort|Ig.Ab"),
                            estimate = c(0.24, 0.07, 0.19),
                            lower = c(0.18, 0.02, 0.13),
                            upper = c(0.31, 0.20, 0.27))

# Combine Parameters for Plot B
d.tunnel <- data.frame(parameter = c("ΨIg.NT", "ΨIg.T", "ΨTort.NT", "ΨTort.T"),
                       estimate = c(0.10, 0.30, 0.26, 0.12),
                       lower = c(0.04, 0.22, 0.16, 0.07),
                       upper = c(0.22, 0.39, 0.40, 0.19))

# Combine Parameters for Plot C
d.PPmgmt <- data.frame(parameter = c("ΨIg.SP", "ΨIg.PP", "ΨTort.SP", "ΨTort.PP"),
                       estimate = c(0.46, 0.13, 0.09, 0.20),
                       lower = c(0.34, 0.08, 0.04, 0.14),
                       upper = c(0.59, 0.21, 0.19, 0.28))

# Create the plots
figA <- ggplot(data = d.conditional, aes(x = parameter, y = estimate)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = upper, ymax = lower), width = 0.15, size = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "black") +
  ylim(0, 0.6) +     # Set y-axis limit
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 9)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "Estimated occupancy probability")

figB <- ggplot(data = d.tunnel, aes(x = parameter, y = estimate)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = upper, ymax = lower), width = 0.3, size = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "black") +
  ylim(0, 0.6) +     # Set y-axis limit
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 9)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")

figC <- ggplot(data = d.PPmgmt, aes(x = parameter, y = estimate)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = upper, ymax = lower), width = 0.3, size = 0.8, color = "black") +
  geom_point(size = 4, shape = 21, fill = "black") +
  ylim(0, 0.6) +     # Set y-axis limit
  theme_bw() +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Arial", size = 9)) +
  labs(x = "", y = "")

# Arrange plots using cowplot
combined_plots <- plot_grid(figA, figB, figC, labels = c("a", "b", "c"), ncol = 3)

# Display the combined plot
combined_plots`

Edit 2: warnings when installing gghx4:
Installing 'ggh4x' ...
[1/4] Installing ggplot2...
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘vctrs’
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
scales     1.1.1  1.3.0              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.0  0.6.5              TRUE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.5.1             FALSE
installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘scales’, ‘vctrs’, ‘ggplot2’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.6.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 569771 bytes (556 KB)
downloaded 556 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763765 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 302544 bytes (295 KB)
downloaded 295 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 969066 bytes (946 KB)
downloaded 946 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3604371 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB

installing source package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
installing source package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
installing source package ‘lifecycle’ ...
** package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
installing source package ‘scales’ ...
** package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘scales’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/scales’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/scales’
installing source package ‘vctrs’ ...
** package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
installing source package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggplot2’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggplot2’
[2/4] Installing vctrs...

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/5k/j_h9b42n257_vkx8y89t94ym0000gn/T/Rtmp2D4q3S/downloaded_packages’
also installing the dependencies ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
cli        3.2.0  3.6.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
vctrs      0.4.0  0.6.5              TRUE
installing the source packages ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘rlang’, ‘vctrs’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.6.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 569771 bytes (556 KB)
downloaded 556 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763765 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 969066 bytes (946 KB)
downloaded 946 KB

installing source package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
installing source package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
installing source package ‘lifecycle’ ...
** package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
installing source package ‘vctrs’ ...
** package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
[3/4] Installing rlang...

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/5k/j_h9b42n257_vkx8y89t94ym0000gn/T/Rtmp2D4q3S/downloaded_packages’
There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
binary source needs_compilation
rlang  1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
installing the source package ‘rlang’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763765 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB

installing source package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
[4/4] Installing ggh4x...

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/5k/j_h9b42n257_vkx8y89t94ym0000gn/T/Rtmp2D4q3S/downloaded_packages’
also installing the dependencies ‘scales’, ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘vctrs’, ‘rlang’
There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
binary source needs_compilation
scales     1.1.1  1.3.0              TRUE
cli        3.2.0  3.6.2              TRUE
lifecycle  1.0.1  1.0.4             FALSE
ggplot2    3.3.5  3.5.1             FALSE
vctrs      0.4.0  0.6.5              TRUE
rlang      1.0.2  1.1.3              TRUE
ggh4x      0.2.1  0.2.8             FALSE
installing the source packages ‘scales’, ‘cli’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘ggplot2’, ‘vctrs’, ‘rlang’, ‘ggh4x’
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/scales_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 302544 bytes (295 KB)
downloaded 295 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/cli_3.6.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 569771 bytes (556 KB)
downloaded 556 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/lifecycle_1.0.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 107656 bytes (105 KB)
downloaded 105 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.5.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3604371 bytes (3.4 MB)
downloaded 3.4 MB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/vctrs_0.6.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 969066 bytes (946 KB)
downloaded 946 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_1.1.3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 763765 bytes (745 KB)
downloaded 745 KB
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/ggh4x_0.2.8.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1308196 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

installing source package ‘cli’ ...
** package ‘cli’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘cli’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/cli’
installing source package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/rlang’
installing source package ‘lifecycle’ ...
** package ‘lifecycle’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/lifecycle’
installing source package ‘scales’ ...
** package ‘scales’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.0.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘scales’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/scales’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/scales’
installing source package ‘vctrs’ ...
** package ‘vctrs’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘vctrs’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/vctrs’
installing source package ‘ggplot2’ ...
** package ‘ggplot2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.12 is being loaded, but >= 1.1.0 is required
Calls:  ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggplot2’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggplot2’
restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggplot2’
installing source package ‘ggh4x’ ...
** package ‘ggh4x’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error: package ‘ggplot2’ 3.3.6 was found, but >= 3.4.2 is required by ‘ggh4x’
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘ggh4x’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/ggh4x’

The downloaded source packages are in
‘/private/var/folders/5k/j_h9b42n257_vkx8y89t94ym0000gn/T/Rtmp2D4q3S/downloaded_packages’
✔ Package 'ggh4x' successfully installed.
There were 18 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

One option would be ggh4x::scale_x_manual which allows to manually set the positions of the breaks for a discrete positional scale. In the code below I move the breaks slightly by +/- .1 for the categories you want to be closer together.
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)
library(ggh4x)

figA <- figA +
  ggh4x::scale_x_manual(
    values = c(1, 2.1, 2.9)
  )

figB <- figB +
  ggh4x::scale_x_manual(
    values = c(1.1, 1.9, 3.1, 3.9)
  )

figC <- figC +
  ggh4x::scale_x_manual(
    values = c(1.1, 1.9, 3.1, 3.9)
  )

combined_plots <- plot_grid(figA, figB, figC,
  labels = c("a", "b", "c"), ncol = 3
)

combined_plots



That looks great! Would I just add that code you posted to the end of what I posted? I tried downloading the ggh4x package but am getting this error: Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘ggh4x’

Hm. Have you run install.packages("ggh4x")? Afterwards you should be able to run my code by adding my code to your script.

I'm getting a bunch of warnings with it, and it's not working. The message is too long for the comments, so I'll edit and add it to the original post above.

The message you get are not related to ggh4x (Actually you get Package 'ggh4x' successfully installed. in the end). The issue is that the installation of some of the dependencies fails. From a look at the package versions you are using it looks like you haven't updated your packages for a while. And concerning the error xcrun: error: invalid active developer see https://forum.posit.co/t/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandlinetools-missing-xcrun-at-library-developer-commandlinetools-usr-bin-xcrun-error-compilation-failed-for-package-rlang/27553/3 for a fix.

That did it! You're a hero. Thank you <3
